# Drupal 7 How to add custom attribute to form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a select drop down list and I wanna add custom attribute attached to each option. Basically I wanna make that form look like this.

```
<select id="audience-segment">
 <optgroup label="Blog">
  <option data-targetaud="GENERAL" value="82">Default</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

How can I add `data-targetaud` using drupal 7 form API or any other way ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_select_options/7.

The options doesn't let you specify any attributes at all.

Comment: ok. Do you have any suggestions how can I bind some extra value with user selection. For example When user pick value 82 I should be able to know target audience (GENERAL) as well. Keep in mind both values are generated dynamically.

Comment: If you just need it for javascript, I would suggest you to build an array with values and use drush_add_js() to add it to the page. 

The key would be the value 82. and the data could be anything, like another array or object that hold all the extra information you need.

Comment: nah thats gonna be a problem.. I need to get the value and pass it to another php function... :(